# How to calculate the Diagonal loading factor evaluate calculate the inversion of a covariance matrix

Tags: matrix, covariance

I am programming a Generalised Likelihood Ratio Test (GLRT) detector. When it comes to inverting a covariance matrix $Ri$, I need  to do a diagonal loading to fix the problem of sigularity of this matrix, but I don't have any info about the technique or algorithm that allows to estimate the right diagonal loading factor factor $\sigma$.

Rather than calculate inverse ($Ri$) I have to calculate inverse ($Ri  +\sigma \cdot I$) where $Ri$ is the covariance matrix.

Need help, please

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: just use $\sigma = 10^{-8}$.
Covariance matrices have eigenvalues $\geq 0$ (theoretically),
so $Ri + 10^{-8} \, I$ will have eigenvalues $\geq 10^{-8}$,
safely non-singular.

A longer answer:
split `Covar = S + N`, "signal" + "noise", by eigenvalues or by SVD,
[Singular-value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition)
aka PCA, [Principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).
This has several advantages:

- gives you an idea of how noisy your Covariance is -- a good thing to know
- you can choose a cutoff, e.g. 98 % of the sum of the eigenvalues,
  or a number of terms, e.g. 3, to plot and look at
- fast, rock-solid implementations:
  in Python,
  [numpy eigvalsh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigvalsh.html),
  [numpy svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html)
  and sparse
  [scipy svds](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html) 
  (sparse, dense or LinOp).

Be careful with large covariance matrices:
eigenvalues can be < 0 because of roundoff,
and they can be very noisy -- see
[here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87032/eigenvalues-of-correlation-matrices-exhibit-exponential-decay)
on stats.stack .

See Press et al. for a good discussion of SVD:
"Solution by use of Singular-value decomposition",
[Numerical Recipes p. 793](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=793) ff.

Comment: thanks for all, I did give the value 1e-9 and 1e-8 to sigma , and it  did correct the problem of sigularity. About the PCA, the great thing that I am trying to understand it nowadays for an other issue I have ; maybe it will fix both issues . thank you again for the response and the link.